# HtmlUnit can't get the js / ajax added of IFRAME

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, iframe, htmlunit

I've just started learning [htmlunit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) by gargoylesoftware and I have a problem.
There is an iframe on a page, which appears after a button click. When i try to get this iframe by name I get a `ElementNotFoundException`. Also I tried `page.getFrames()` and it returns frames, but there is no frame that i'm looking for or it is blank. So It looks like js/ajax didn't update it. I work on jcpenny(dot)com and problem appears when I try to "checkout" from "My Bag" page
Here is my WebClient settings

```
BrowserVersion bv = BrowserVersion.CHROME_16;
bv.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)");
CookieManager cm = new CookieManager();
cm.clearCookies();
cm.setCookiesEnabled(true);
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(bv);
webClient.setCookieManager(cm);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());
webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(15000);
webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(15000);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
webClient.setRefreshHandler(new ThreadedRefreshHandler());
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be late answer, but it will be useful for others in the future.

```
HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getWebWindowByName("Frame Name").getEnclosedPage();
```

hope this will help to identify iframes.

Comment: What if iframe doen't have name? The iframe which i am trying to access have id not name.
<iframe class="text" id="frameJobDescription" style="width:548px;" frameborder="0" src="" tabindex="-1" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" height="210"></iframe>