# How to get the content of a specific iframe using HtmlUnit. Iframe doesn't have name but it has ID

Tags: java, ajax, iframe, htmlunit

I want to get the content of a specific iframe using HtmlUnit. From one of the post ([HtmlUnit can't get the js / ajax added of IFRAME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866694/htmlunit-cant-get-the-js-ajax-added-of-iframe)) I got an idea that I can use this code:

```
HtmlPage currentPage = (HtmlPage)webClient.getWebWindowByName("Frame Name").getEnclosedPage();
```

But the issue is that iframe doen't have name. The iframe which i am trying to access have id not name. Something like this:

```
<iframe class="text" id="frameContent" style="width:548px;" frameborder="0" src="" tabindex="-1" allowtransparency="true" scrolling="no" height="210"></iframe>
```

How to get the content in this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
HtmlPage page = client.getPage("http://example.com/");
List<FrameWindow> frames = page.getFrames();
for (FrameWindow frame : frames) {
    if (frame.getFrameElement().getId().equals("frameContent")) {
        page = (HtmlPage) frame.getEnclosedPage();
    }
}
```